# PGFPlots keys for axes and plot styles only partially working

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys

I'm trying to plot different views of a 3D curve, but I'd like to define the axes and the plots' style from the beginning; I haven't been able to do this. Here's the code and what I get:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function ={
            ex(\x)=cos(\x)*sin(2*\x);
            ye(\x)=cos(\x)*cos(2*\x);
            ze(\x)=sin(\x);
        }
    ]
    \pgfplotsset{
        every axis post/.append style={
            trig format plots=rad,
            scale=0.7
        }
        every axis plot/.append style={
            blue,
            domain=0:2*pi,
            samples=120 
        }
    }
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot3 ({ex(x)},{ye(x)},{ze(x)});
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[xshift=7cm, view/h=120,view/v=90]
    \addplot3 ({ex(x)},{ye(x)},{ze(x)});
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I want is the following (obtained writing all the above options into every `axis` env. and every `\addplot` macro):
[image]

The curve colour does take on, but not the rest of the options. I don't really know if I'm using the right syntax for the keys; it clearly is correct syntax, because I can compile with no errors, but I am obviously missing something to get what I want and I can't seem to find it in the manual. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a comma between the two `pgfplotsset` parts (the `every axis post` part and the `every axis plot` part). Also you need an empty option set `[]` after `\addplot3` to trigger the general setting.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function ={
            ex(\x)=cos(\x)*sin(2*\x);
            ye(\x)=cos(\x)*cos(2*\x);
            ze(\x)=sin(\x);
        }
    ]
    \pgfplotsset{
        every axis post/.append style={
            trig format plots=rad,
            scale=0.7
        },
        every axis plot/.append style={
            purple,
            domain=0:2*pi,
            samples=120 
        }
    }
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[] ({ex(x)},{ye(x)},{ze(x)});
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[xshift=7cm, view/h=120,view/v=90]
    \addplot3[] ({ex(x)},{ye(x)},{ze(x)});
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Now I am VERY ashamed. Thanks!